# ImageMagick failed in XAMPP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I had installed ImageMagick in XAMPP 1.8.1 come with PHP 5.4.7. I want to have thumb generate in JPG while uploading PDF file. I follow this guide  (http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/) to installing the dll and test run the script, but end up I get below error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'imagick' not found in C:\...
```

What's wrong come with this installation?

**SOLUTION:**

I just got it to work by installed ImageMagick 6.8.0. I use the package here: http://valokuva.org/?p=197

Comment: did you check `phpinfo`, does it list the module?

Answer (score 0):

set the path in environment variable
First go to the system properties and click on environment variables and give the path of imagemagick library path in PATH variable.

```
C:\ImageMagick
```

Comment: where is the system properties?

Comment: click on window icon and put environment variables in search box.